# Cant open nautilus or gnome terminal on 19.04

Tags: nautilus, gnome-terminal, 19.04

When I press open on nautilus or terminal on Ubuntu 19.04, the loading indicator appears in the top left, but it doesn't open. I can use polo file manager to browse files and use xterm for commands and nautilus opens if i type "nautilus" in xterm.

Comment: Open Xterm and run `gnome-terminal`. If there are errors, [edit] your question and paste them.

Comment: how did you get to ubuntu 19.04? fresh install or upgrade?

Comment: I got to 19.04 by updating to beta

Comment: how do you copy from xterm on laptop?

Comment: You can redirect the output to a file using `> 1.txt` after the command, i.e. `gnome-terminal > 1.txt` and then paste the content of that file.

Comment: same here, just upgraded from 18.10 to 19.04
any solution for this?

Comment: to copy from terminal first highlight then hold down  ...  control + shift + c  ...   then to paste do a ...  control + v ... I am using 19.04 just fine ... both from upgrade from earlier release or from fresh install

Answer (score 3):

Mainly it appears that there's a bug, not sure what it is. It uses masses of system resources which is why you can't open nautilus. I found a reinstall worked

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
```

I also found that installing unity worked for other services like terminal.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

It's a work round that works until they fix gnome

Comment: Is there any Unity left in Ubuntu 19.04?

Comment: yes and it works splendidly well; don't know why they haven't added it as a fall back, its way faster and of course has the HUD, it is an offshoot of gnome its self but one that would appear to out class the desktop that was supposed to take its place. jus in case id better give th how to remove as well.

Comment: If you need to remove it .
sudo apt purge unity-session unity

sudo apt autoremove

Make Sure Ubuntu Session and GDM3 Are Still Installed
sudo apt install ubuntu-session gdm3
Restart Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I had a `nautilus.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications` which I created myself so that nautilus opens without managing the desktop (because I use i3) by supplying the `--no-desktop` option. This option has now been removed from the recent version of Nautilus, I had to remove it in the desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
NotShowIn=GNOME
Name=Files
Comment=Access and organize files
Exec=nautilus --new-window
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and couldn't play any sound as well.

By running `snap list` I noticed that there where two versions of gnome installed.
So I just remove the older one by running `snap remove gnome-<older version>`

Answer (score 0):

If files and sound system is also not working probably that's because you installed chrome-remote-desktop.
Remove it by the following command,it helped for me. And don't forget to restart.
`sudo apt-get remove chrome-remote-desktop`