# Nautilus and Terminal refuse to run on Ubuntu 19.04 (up-to-date as of 14 June 2019)

Tags: command-line, nautilus, 19.04

After clicking on them, it loads for a while then nothing happens.

Currently using Tilda and Dolphin as I do not have access to my filesystem and the terminal.

Somehow Nautilus runs when I run it from Tilda command line.

Tried these fixes but to no avail:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus

sudo apt-get autoremove libdvd-pkg
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

These fixes are from:
[Cant open nautilus or gnome terminal on 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136364/cant-open-nautilus-or-gnome-terminal-on-19-04)

[libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094062/libdvd-pkg-apt-get-check-failed-you-may-have-broken-packages-aborting)

Ran gnome-terminal and got this:

```
munem@Munem-G74SX:~$ gnome-terminal
# _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation gvfs (GDaemonVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’
# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

Comment: Hi, I did some desperate research on this matter and it turns out the problems were caused by Chrome Remote Desktop!

Ran sudo apt-get remove chrome-remote-desktop, restarted my Ubuntu 19.04 and everything works fine again! I am so glad.

Can the mods mark this as solved?

Comment: Post that as an answer and mark it as accepted after 48 hours.

Comment: @Kulfy Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Chrome Remote Desktop is causing all these issues. It was from a Ubuntu forum post.

Remove Chrome Remote Desktop solves all these!

Run

```
sudo apt-get remove chrome-remote-desktop
```

Then restart.

Voila!